# Freshly checked out program, won't let me update because of Checkout Conflict

Tags: eclipse, git

So there's two developers on my project, me and the other guy.  The other guy is doing most of the coding and I wanted to use Github to store our code.  This lead to the install of Egit for eclipse.  We're both working on Windows.

He is able to do commits and pushes to the remote repository no problem.  I can see that changes have been made with the little down arrow thingy in the project name (after I've done a fetch).

I cannot do a merge.  I get Checkout conflict: Your local changes to blah blah blah.

I haven't touched the code.  Does anyone know how I might do a merge force from within the Eclipse plugin?

I also wouldn't hate answers to the following question:

What is the difference between Commit, Push to Upstream, Fetch from Upstream, Fetch, Push, Merge and Synchronize workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't edited the code and are running into merge conflicts when pulling right away, it's most likely because you've versioned files which your IDE is automatically modifying. This probably includes local, user-specific configuration files that are not actually part of the source code.

> What is the difference between Commit, Push to Upstream, Fetch from Upstream, Fetch, Push, Merge and Synchronize workspace.

You probably want to familiarize yourself with git itself first. All of those, except for "synchronize workspace", are git commands, and you can find the documentation for them on [the website](http://git-scm.com/documentation).

Comment: Yes, that sounds quite likely.  I hadn't thought of the IDE making its own changes.  As to the other question, I was really hoping not to have to know more about git than I wanted (the documentation is rather verbose) but I'll just live with it and spend the time. :-)

Comment: Git is as powerful and flexible as it is complicated (comparatively to e.g. SVN or Mercurial)... you may run into problems when using it without fully understanding the basic principles. You could check other git resources such as intro/tutorial videos rather than going through the official documentation.